# Как узнать директорию в консоле с которой запущен файл

Tags: c++, консоль, c++11

Можно ли как-то узнать в какой директории в консоле находиться пользователь?

Пишу программу на С++, как правило её будут вызывать именно с консоли, нужно знать путь в котором находился пользователь во время вызова, передавать как аргумент не удобно.

Брать с argv[] не предлагать, там путь к исполняемому файлу.

Спасибо.

Comment: В С++17 в `<filesystem>` есть функция под это.

Comment: Думаю, лучше подсказать имя https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path();
    return 0;
}
```